# two seperate git versions - want to use the brew installed version

Tags: git, homebrew

As I got a notification from heroku that my git is outdated, I wanted to upgrade it using "brew upgrade git" then I got this:

```
Error: git not installed
```

Wtf? Ok so I decided to use brew to install it:

```
$ brew install git
```

Ok that worked. Git 2.2.2 was installed.
Now when checking

```
$ git --version
```

I get

```
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
```

No clue what is going on but it seems that I have two git versions installed on my machine now. 2.2.2 and 1.9.3 which I don't want to use anymore.
I'm not a console master so I'm clueless also after researching how to solve that mess.
Any hints?

Comment: Do you have XCode installed? If I'm not mistaken, XCode installs a lot of dependencies globally. If you want to use your own library, you need to upgrade your $PATH variable.

Comment: probably git was already installed by something else than brew; and `git --version` would have given you `git version 1.9.3` as well... maybe try uninstalling git using brew; and see what `git --version` gives?

Comment: without brew, I get git version 1.9.3. So brew is owning the 2.2.2 version and something else the 1.9.3 version. How can I get rid off 1.9.3 for good?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `brew doctor`?

It will tell if anything is wrong with your `PATH` environment variable, which is most likely the issue.

Comment: Not a lot of feedback I can help you with. Have you tried running `which git`, `echo $PATH`, ...? What do those return?

Answer (score 0):

`homebrew` installs everything in `/usr/local/bin`, so if you want to use packages installed by `homebrew` in preference to Apple-supplied programs, you need to put that at the start of your PATH, i.e. add a line in your login profile that says

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```